# Removing the ' ' at the beginning and end of printed list

Tags: python, python-3.x

As the title suggests; I am trying to remove the '' at the beginning and end of a list that is printed. The code is working mostly correctly i believe - this is what i have thus far;

```
import sys

ls1 = []
inputintegers = input("Enter some integers: ")
ls1.append(inputintegers)

print("Your integers were: {}".format(ls1))
```

What i get in return is

```
Enter some integers: 1, 8, 5, 4, 8  
Your integers were: ['1, 8, 5, 4, 8']
```

when i want to get:

```
Enter some integers: 1, 8, 5, 4, 8  
Your integers were: [1, 8, 5, 4, 8]
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn’t the quote at the beginning and the end of the list.

The problem is that *you are not parsing the input string*. You think you’re storing a list of numbers, but you’re not. You’re storing a *single string*.

You need to parse the user input:

```
user_input = input("Enter some integers: ").strip()
ls1 = [int(x) for x in user_input.split(', ')]
```

With this, there’s no need to (a) pre-declare `ls1` or (b) call `.append`.